# How to use two different records from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a query to get results from the database. The results are then saved in an array. I want to know how can I use those results from array to get further results from the database in a single query. Or I'll have to use multiple queries?

```
   $query2="SELECT officeName FROM office 
WHERE parentOfficeID='$parent'";

$result2=mysqli_query($connect,$query2); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) != 0)
{
$results= array();
 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
      {
           $results[]=$row2['officeName'];
      }
}
```

The $results array saves the results. I want to use the officeName values individually. Is there any way I use single query? Or I'll have to process each value?

Comment: You can do this with an inner join on the table itself, something like : SELECT x.officeName FROM office as x INNER JOIN office AS y ON x.officeName = y.Something WHERE x.parentOfficeId = $variable;

Comment: You should parameterize your variable. Security issue.

Comment: you can use sub queries http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If I understand your question then first you want to fetch some `officeName`  and store them in array and then want to fetch some other info based on that `officeName` . You can use this one

```
<?php 
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','databasename');
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT officeName FROM office WHERE parentOfficeID='$parent'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
$officeName = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){          
$officeName[] = $row['officeName'];//store your office name in an array
}        
$officeName= join("', '", $officeName);//The join() function returns a string from the elements of an array. It is an alias of the implode() function.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM office WHERE officeName IN ('$officeName')";// query with IN condition
$result1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
echo "<pre>";print_r($row1);
}
```

for more info more about `join()`. Please read http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_join.asp

for `mysqli` `IN condition` please read http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Nyranith, you could also swap out your while statement and use

`mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Which will return your values as an associative array without the need for you to loop through and build the array yourself.

It's been a really long time since I used mysqli, could need tweaking but here goes.

Here's a better way to go about the process itself:
Assume you have tables: Office and Staff and for some reason, you are binding the office to staff by the office name (bad juju)
$parent = 1;

```
$query2="SELECT o.officeName, s.name  
FROM office AS o
INNER JOIN staff AS s ON o.officeName = s.officeName 
WHERE o.parentOfficeID=?";

$stmt = $connect->prepare($query2);
$query = $stmt->bindParam($parent);
$exec = $stmt->execute();
$results2 = mysqli_fetch_all($exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Now, do something with your result array

```
foreach($results2 as $key => $value) {
    //loop through your results an do another query with them. Just like you queried the database to get these results.
}
```

Comment: Sir I think it does not answer question. I want to use the array elements to retrieve further results from the database.

Comment: You can use the array results to do whatever you wish. I'll add an example.